# How to make a Facebook post hidden using the Graph API or FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, feed

I am creating a moderating application in which i need to fetch all the posts on a page and then set the posts to be hidden if required. In Facebook, there is an option to set a post as hidden. How do I do this using the Graph API or FQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a few weeks, you can make a POST request to the post object with the parameter "is_hidden" :

```
curl –F 'is_hidden=true" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/<POST_ID>?access_token=_"
```

Check the documentation at "Hiding a Page Post" :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check out [the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), regarding the **privacy** field.